# Can't install minimesos on Vagrant -- Failed to run command 'up'. null

Tags: ubuntu, docker, centos, vagrant, minimesos

I tested both on CentOS 7.3 and Ubuntu 16.04. The docker version is different, but the virtual environment are the same. One workstation with multiple VMs on Vagrant.

## CentOS 7.3

```
[root@localhost ~]# docker version
Client:
 Version:         1.12.6
 API version:     1.24
 Package version: docker-common-1.12.6-16.el7.centos.x86_64
 Go version:      go1.7.4
 Git commit:      3a094bd/1.12.6
 Built:           Fri Apr 14 13:46:13 2017
 OS/Arch:         linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:         1.12.6
 API version:     1.24
 Package version: docker-common-1.12.6-16.el7.centos.x86_64
 Go version:      go1.7.4
 Git commit:      3a094bd/1.12.6
 Built:           Fri Apr 14 13:46:13 2017
 OS/Arch:         linux/amd64

[root@localhost ~]# curl -sSL https://minimesos.org/install | sh
[root@localhost ~]# export PATH=$PATH:/home/alg/.minimesos/bin
[root@localhost ~]# minimesos up
Pulling containersol/minimesos-cli:0.13.0
Trying to pull repository docker.io/containersol/minimesos-cli ...
0.13.0: Pulling from docker.io/containersol/minimesos-cli

b7f33cc0b48e: Pull complete
43a564ae36a3: Pull complete
efb75a810eee: Pull complete
caf0c110d33e: Pull complete
aadff284a195: Pull complete
26bffb7df44f: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:abe376953d06aee44e66545d228e7738afad28acbb80d221f10f1d5dd699c783
Failed to run command 'up'. null
```

## Ubuntu 16.04

```
root@vagrant:~# docker version
Client:
 Version:      17.05.0-ce
 API version:  1.29
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   89658be
 Built:        Thu May  4 22:10:54 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.05.0-ce
 API version:  1.29 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   89658be

root@vagrant:~# curl -sSL https://minimesos.org/install | sh
root@vagrant:~# export PATH=$PATH:/home/alg/.minimesos/bin
root@vagrant:~# minimesos up
Pulling containersol/minimesos-cli:0.13.0
0.13.0: Pulling from containersol/minimesos-cli
b7f33cc0b48e: Pull complete
43a564ae36a3: Pull complete
efb75a810eee: Pull complete
caf0c110d33e: Pull complete
aadff284a195: Pull complete
26bffb7df44f: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:abe376953d06aee44e66545d228e7738afad28acbb80d221f10f1d5dd699c783
Status: Downloaded newer image for containersol/minimesos-cli:0.13.0
Failed to run command 'up'. null
```

Both of them return this error:

```
Failed to run command 'up'. null
```

I have search from Google to try to find something, also delete all the docker images to keep a fresh environment, but the result are the same. Is it because of network? Or anything others? I don't know.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the image.

Comment: @MattSchuchard Really? So there is no way to success.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely that you have not created a `minimesosFile` yet.

Run `minimesos init` first and then try again running `minimesos up`.

Comment: Even run that, the same result.